# Suppose if I want to press Delete button 9 times in my CODED UI code, is there any shortcut or do I need to give keyboard control 9 times in code?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

Suppose if I want to press Delete button 9 times in my CODEDUI code, is there any shortcut or I need to give keyboard control 9 times in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a for loop to loop through clicking the control 9 times:

```
for(var i = 0;i < 9;i++)
{
    Mouse.Click(UiControl.DeleteButton);
}
```

You can place this in a method in your .UiMap file, or in your testmethod.

Some unasked advice: If you want to click delete 9 times because you have 9 items you want to delete 9 items from a table or another element you could try to get the count of the children:

```
var deleteNum = UiControl.Table.GetChildren().Count;
for(var i = 0; i < deleteNum; i++ )
{
    Mouse.Click(UiControl.DeleteButton);
}
```

This will help as you won't use the control more than it should, and will make sure your testmethods are more robust against changes in the application.

Comment: Both `for` loops have a test using `==` which means their bodies will never be executed (unless `deleteNum` is actually zero in the second loop). I think you meant `<` for both loops.

Comment: The loop `for(var i = 0;i <= 9;i++) {...}` will be executed 10 times, which I why I suggested `<` in the earlier comment. Similarly for the second loop, it will execute once more time than desired.

Comment: I'm not sure why I'm having so much trouble with a simple for loop, but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a click example using WinAPI - since it's faster than control identification.

```
public static class AppManager
   {
      private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
      private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;

[DllImport("user32.dll",
         CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
         CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
      private static extern void mouse_event(long dwFlags,
         long dx,
         long dy,
         long cButtons,
         long dwExtraInfo);

public static void RapidClick(Point pt)
      {
         Cursor.Position = pt;
         mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, pt.X, pt.Y, 0, 0);
      }
}
```

Then to use RapidClick, I do this:

```
var point = new Point(control.Left+1, control.Top + 1);             

            for (int pos = 0; pos < totalClicks; pos++)
            {
                AppManager.RapidClick(point);
            }
```

The benefits of this is that the performance is mindblowingly fast. This is because you do a lookup to the control once to get the initial co-ordinates, after that you can rapid click it reliably.

This has worked for me locally, and also no issues with RDC or in labs environment too.

Comment: Is the only speed increase because of the lookup not being needed every iteration? Wouldn't `Mouse.Click(point)` be as fast?

Comment: @Thomas I haven't tried that - perhaps it would be as fast.